# Stored Proc : Use Return or Select at end?

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

If I'm creating a C# wrapper for a stored proc, and that sp only returns/selects (not sure) 1 value, should I use return or select at the end of that sp?

This is for t-sql.

Answer (score 6):

**Return** can only return (no pun intended) an integer  and you can only return 1 value

An **output parameter** can return all datatypes and you can have multiple output parameters per proc

A **select** statement can return a resultset

It all depends what you want to accomplish in your calling code, I myself prefer output parameters

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple choices. You can use an OUTPUT parameter to your stored procedure, a Select statement, or a return value. If I had to guess, I would say an OUTPUT parameter would be the most commonly used given your situation.

Comment: +1. It's also much easier to chain procedure calls when using `OUTPUT` parameters rather than a result set or a return value.